# Dynamic variable at the end of foreach in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables

im trying to create a small status script, checking ram, cpu og drives. Right now im doing a foreach on get volume. Is it possible to create a variable in the end of my foreach called driveletter + output

So the variable could look like this `$Coutput` or `$Doutput`, depending on the driveletter?

```sh
$ByteDivider = 1073741824

$Disks = Get-Volume | Select -ExpandProperty Driveletter

foreach($disk in $disks){

$DrivLetter = Get-Volume -DriveLetter $disk | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Driveletter

$Size = Get-Volume -DriveLetter $disk | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Size
$SizeInGB = $Size/$ByteDivider
$SizeRounded = '{0:f0}' -f $SizeInGB


$FreeSpace = Get-Volume -DriveLetter $disk | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SizeRemaining
$FreeSpaceInGB = $FreeSpace/$ByteDivider

$UsedSpace = $SizeInGB-$FreeSpaceInGB
$UsedSpaceRounded = '{0:f0}' -f $UsedSpace

Write-Host ("Drive: $DrivLetter Used:$UsedSpaceRounded/$SizeRounded")

}
```

Comment: What is `output` to you? So you want variables that read `$Cused:312/121`?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
New-Variable -Name $disk+Output -Value $data -Force
```